# Dini derivative and Gronwoll's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

Proposition: Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b)$, and $g$ be a smooth function (that is $C^{\infty} function$) on $[a,b)$.
Assume that $g$ is positive  and monotonically decreasing on $[a,b)$.

Then $D_{+}(fg)(t)=D_{+}f(t) g(t)+f(t) D_{+}g(t)$.

Here $D_{+}f$ is defined by 
$$\liminf_{h \to +0} \frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\ \ \ \ \ \ $$  for $t \in [a,b)$

And $fg$ is defined by $fg(t):=f(t)g(t)$.

Question: Is this proposition true or not?

If this is NOT true ,please teach me some counter example.

I'd appreciate if you could answer this questions.